# Write GeoTIFF in Python without GDAL

Tags: python, geotiff-tiff

I have a code to transform numpy array in TIFF image using Pillow. But now I need to georeference the tiff to later use it in a GIS software. In my case, I have the latitude and longitude of each of my pixel and I would like to have my GeoTIFF tagged in a specific projection which I have the definition in a .prj along with a shapefile.

I know how to do it with GDAL but I am looking for a way to do it with Pillow or another low dependency package in Python.

Comment: Short of manually writing a .tfw and a .prj alongside your tiff, it might be tough to find a package that doesn't itself depend on gdal.  Why specifically do you want to avoid it?  Many dependency-related woes can be avoided with something like virtualenv or anaconda

Comment: You can use a .prj alongside a tiff like a shp?

Comment: Probably not, now that you mention it

Comment: Well ok, I had codes with pillow already but I guess if I want GeoTIFF I will need to recode on GDAL.

Comment: This may help: https://pypi.org/project/tifffile/

Answer (score 2):

As you have the latitude and longitude of the pixels, yo can write a tfw file (world file)
According to [Wikipedia: world file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_file)

> The generic meaning of the six parameters in a world file (as defined by Esri[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_file)) are:
>   Line 1: A: pixel size in the x-direction in map units/pixel
>   Line 2: D: rotation about y-axis
>   Line 3: B: rotation about x-axis
>   Line 4: E: pixel size in the y-direction in map units, almost always negative[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yjjZs.png)
>   Line 5: C: x-coordinate of the center of the upper left pixel
>   Line 6: F: y-coordinate of the center of the upper left pixel
>   All four parameters are expressed in the map units, which are described by the spatial reference system for the raster.

1) It is easy to  get
- Line 5 (x-coordinate of the center of the upper left pixel -> **uplx** -> red point)
- Line 6 (y-coordinate of the center of the upper left pixel **uply** -> red point)

2) With 3 points you can compute:
- Line 1 (pixel size in the x-direction in map units/pixel->**ppx** -> red and green points)
- Line 4 (pixel size in the y-direction in map units, negative ->**ppy**, red and blue points)

3) Generally the values of Line 2 and Line 3 are zero

[image]

4) Save the resulting worldfile (text file)

```
worldfile = open('raster.tfw', "w")  
worldfile.write(str(ppx)+"\n")
worldfile.write(str(0)+"\n") # generally = 0
worldfile.write(str(0)+"\n") # generally = 0
worldfile.write(str(ppy)+"\n")
worldfile.write(str(uplx)+"\n")
worldfile.write(str(uply)+"\n")
worldfile.close()
```

5) The projection is the projection of the x and y of the pixels (longitude, latitude  in your case -> WGS84 projection, [EPSG 4326](http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/4326/) and the )